# configure nginx with shibboleth

Tags: nginx, shibboleth

I need to get Nginx working with Shibboleth.
I have followed several guides and have come to this point.
I need to be able to access the path /VerificaGel
The moment I type the url a browser gives a 500 error.
Can you help me?

```
    location = /shibauthorizer {
      internal;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/shibboleth/shibauthorizer.sock;
    }
    
    location /Shibboleth.sso {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/shibboleth/shibresponder.sock;
    }
    
    location /shibboleth-sp {
      alias /usr/share/shibboleth/;
    }
    
    # Login location configuration
    
    location /VerificaGel {
      #root html;
      #index index.html;
      include /etc/moduli/nginx-http-shibboleth/includes/shib_clear_headers;
      more_clear_input_headers 'Variable-*' 'Shib-*' 'Remote-User' 'REMOTE_USER' 'Auth-Type' 'AUTH_TYPE';
      more_clear_input_headers 'displayName' 'mail' 'persistent-id';
      shib_request /shibauthorizer;
      
      proxy_pass http://mysite/Shibboleth.sso;
    }

        
}
}
```